# AWS SNS create million files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have an event stream which send millions of events through SNS every day. Through a lambda, these topics are then stored in s3 but each in its own file. Total size of these events is not much (less than 1 GB) but moving/deleting one day files each the size of a few bytes becomes a long process. Is there a way I can store these SNS topics into larger files (or even a single file)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd have the Lambda write the events to Kinesis Data Firehose and use that to batch the events up to a certain size-threshold or time-window and then have Firehose deliver those to S3.

Here are some resources for that:

- [S3 Destination for the delivery stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-destination.html#create-destination-s3)
- [S3 Destination buffer size & interval](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-configure.html)

Answer (score 1):

SNS with kinesis firehose looks perfect fit for this use case.

Recently aws announced [kinesis firehouse support with SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-firehose-as-subscriber.html), on kinesis you can add bufferring conditions to s3.

> Kinesis Data Firehose buffers incoming data before delivering it (backing it up) to Amazon S3. You can choose a buffer size of 1–128 MiBs and a buffer interval of 60–900 seconds. The condition that is satisfied first triggers data delivery to Amazon S3

In case you want to transform your events or process them you can use lambda as well.